# How to scrape data from website when It display false response

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from a website but I'm getting one error. As I'm new to web scraping so plese guide me how to fix this issue. here is the issue that I am facing UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment

here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') # 1. html , 2. parser
    return soup
def get_detail_page(soup):
     try:
        title = (soup.find('h1',class_="ProductTitle-title",id=False).text)
     except:
         title = 'Empty Title'
     try:
        title = (soup.find('h1',class_="TopBar-perUnit TopBar-perUnitTop",id=False).text)
     except:
         price = 'Empty price'   
     try:
        img = (soup.find('img',class_="ViewSelectorItem-image",id=False).get('src'))
     except:
        img = 'Empty img'
     data = {
         'Title'        : title,
         'Price'        : price,
         'Img'          : img
     }
     print(data)
def main():
    url = "https://www.zazzle.com/60th_silver_diamond_anniversary_photo_invitations-161837951427094549"
    get_detail_page(get_page(url))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: in your `get_page` function `soup` is not defined when the status code is not response.ok (200)

Comment: thank you sir. Could you please let me know why my status code is not response.ok(200)? Is any solution?

Comment: it returns 403 with a captcha check try opening the site in an incognito tab

Comment: try setting the user-agent header (with a real one)

Comment: Sir is there any solution to scrape data from that website?

Comment: how to set user-agent header?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Answer (score 0):

I've added the user-agent to your code:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


REQUEST_HEADER = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
                  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"}

def get_page(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=REQUEST_HEADER)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=20).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    return soup


def get_detail_page(soup):
    try:
       title = (soup.find('h1',class_="ProductTitle-title",id=False).text)
    except:
        title = 'Empty Title'
    try:
       title = (soup.find('h1',class_="TopBar-perUnit TopBar-perUnitTop",id=False).text)
    except:
        price = 'Empty price'   
    try:
       img = (soup.find('img',class_="ViewSelectorItem-image",id=False).get('src'))
    except:
       img = 'Empty img'
    data = {
        'Title'        : title,
        'Price'        : price,
        'Img'          : img
    }
    print(data)


def main():
    url = "https://www.zazzle.com/60th_silver_diamond_anniversary_photo_invitations-161837951427094549"
    get_detail_page(get_page(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, a pretty interesting read: [Google Chrome: Change the User-Agent String](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-change-user-agent-string)